# How to return an array using .C interface to R

Tags: r, c

I have this simple bit of code:

```
    void test(int *testvec,  int *testlen, int *testres) {

        for (int i = 0; i < *testlen; i++){
        testres[i]=0;
        if (testvec[i] < 0){
            testres[i] = -1;}
        else if (testvec[i] == 0){
            testres[i] = 0;}
        else {testres[i] = 1;}
    }
  }
}
```

When I pass

```
testresult = function (testvec, len){
  signC = .C("signC", as.integer(testvec), as.integer(length(testvec)), as.integer(testvector("integer"), length(testvec))) 
  return (signC)
}
testvec = c(1,2,-3,0,2)
```

It seems that nothing has been processed.
I am pretty new to C and I can't understand how to assign a value to an array dynamically within the contest of .C interface within R.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any particular reason for using the `.C` interface over the more versatile `.Call` interface?

Comment: We have to use it as part of a course of study. Can't do otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.C` interface functions can’t return values. If you want to modify values in C, you need to pass a vector of sufficient size into the function, and write into that vector:

```
sign = function (testvec) {
    sign_c = integer(length(testvec))
    .C("signC", as.integer(testvec), length(testvec), sign_c)
    sign_c
}
```

Comment: Thank you Konrad, I have amended the post to show that I created a function with two parameters rather than one and passed the length of the returning value directly as param.  Getting rid of the sign_c at the end of your function it works fine.